# How to avoid selenium in linux enrivolment reseting user data directory?

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am using selenium in python to do automation tasks, but it requires chrome profiles with special settings. So I am using

```
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=path_to_chrome_file")
```

to load profiled chrome. I am also using following options:

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
ignored_exceptions = (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="chromedriver")

stealth(
    driver,
    languages=["en-US", "en"],
    vendor="Google Inc.",
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
    renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
    fix_hairline=True,
)
```

Some of options may not necessary, just because added along time.

Problem:
I found that, sometimes (around 1/20 times), the file setting present in "--user-data-dir=path_to_chrome_file" will be cleared and generate the new data file. Can someone help figure out why is this happens?

The same code struture and options works well in windows.

Comment: _sometimes (around 1/20 times)_: Exactly when?

Comment: Actually I am running more than 20 different profiles, but I find out that the problem is related to path. Dont know why some runs, the path is not exist, so I added "if os.path.exists(path):" to check existence. At least with this, it will not reset the profile.